# Interlacing two columns together in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to figure out how to interlace/merge two columns together:

how can I merge two columns of data into one like the following:

```
Name   Age    Age_1
========================
A       18       
B              45
C       31       
D       15         
E              62
```

into this

```
Name   Age    
============
A       18       
B       45      
C       31       
D       15         
E       62
```

In my case I have like maybe 3 - 4 similar columns and 200 rows

Comment: Open to VBA solution?

Comment: Sure, not familiar with VBA, I do know Python so I might be able to wrap my head around it

Comment: Are the columns all filled with positive integers? If so, the max function seems ideal to me. The blanks will be treated as 0's. So in your first row `MAX(18, 0)` will give you 18 etc.... If you have 4 columns it will look something like `MAX(18, 0, 0, 0) which will give same output

Comment: @urdearboy, why would max return zero for blank or `""` cells? It should ignore them.

Comment: @user11121185 yup. Good call - too tired. Logging offffff

Comment: Just use `=SUM()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### VBA Solution

To implement: `Open VBE > On Project Explorer > ThisWorkbook > Paste Code > Click Play (Green button up top)`

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub Merger()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim Target As Range, LR As Long

LR = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each Target In ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)
    If Target = "" Then
        Target.Value = Target.Offset(0, 1).Value
    End If
Next Target

'If you want to delete Column C after
ws.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Delete

End Sub
```

---

### Non-VBA Solution

Create a helper column (`Column D`) and place the following equation in `D2`

```
'If your columns may contain text
=IF(B2 = "", C2, B2)

'If your columns only contains positive numbers
=MAX(B2, C2)
```

Once you drop the equation down to the bottom, you will have a new column that is merged. You can paste as values and just delete your other columns or just reference your new column and leave the other two there for reference

Answer (score 3):

If you can add the resulting column, try this:

[image]

This would be the formula in cell D3 which you can copy downwards and customize the B3:C3 cells to include the other columns:

```
=TEXTJOIN("";TRUE;B3:C3)
```

Comment: This is a good solution here since OP will need to extend to multiple columns and you just need to adjust the range in `TEXTJOIN` to implement this. Only skepticism is that this function is relatively new and not available to all users due to outdated version

Comment: @urdearboy I agree. Should have asked which excel version he's working with. Thought it was a quick solution maybe could help somebody else too.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `CONCATENATE` function

[image]

---

### **Edited**

If you just only want to allow "**Numbers**" you can replace your function with this one:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(CONCATENATE(R3:U3)),"")
```

[image]

`IFERROR()`: `IFERROR(value, [value_if_error])`

`VALUE()`: Converts a date/time/number string into a number

`CONCATENATE()`: `CONCATENATE(string1, [string2, ...])`

---

I hope I've been able to help you

Comment: Should that be `=--concatenate(p2:s2)`?

Comment: @user11121185 - Why the `--`? Also, I think this is the easiest answer for OP, assuming their table is that simple. No VBA, no `TEXTJOIN()` (in case OP doesn't have that function). Nice thinking.

Comment: The *double unary* (or `--`) will take the text string Santiago has concatenated into a true number.

Comment: I'm not sure how CONCATENATE will work in this case. It isn't working for me. I get the #VALUE error.

Comment: @user11121185, I've edited the answer to allow only numbers

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler options is to,

1. Select the data range in either of the 2 columns like below,

   [image: fillupBlanksWithDataFromAdjacentColumn-1]
2. Post selecting the data range in one of the columns, select blank cells by pressing F5 fn key and then selecting 'Blanks' as shown in the image below,

   [image: fillupBlanksWithDataFromAdjacentColumn-select-blank-cells]

   This would be the resulting selection in your case,

   [image: fillupBlanksWithDataFromAdjacentColumn-select-blank-cells-result]
3. You will now have to enter a formula (While all blank cells in the target column are selected by completing the previous step, the formula you enter now will initially be with reference to the cell which is currently in focus. The current cell in focus can be known from the Address bar)

   Start typing the formula by pressing the "=" sign as shown in the image below,

   [image: fillupBlanksWithDataFromAdjacentColumn-enter-formula-in-blank-cell]

   Now select the adjacent cell which contains the value that needs to be copied as shown in the image below

   [image: fillupBlanksWithDataFromAdjacentColumn-enter-formula-in-blank-cell-select-copy-source-cell]
4. Once selected as shown in the above image, press Ctrl + Enter. Voila!

   [image: fillupBlanksWithDataFromAdjacentColumn-enter-formula-in-blank-cell-select-paste-down-to-all-by-Ctrl+Enter]

Hope this helps. Should be easier, as you try this in more real time scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to merge the B:E cells in each row where B is blank then immediately unmerge them. This will have the effect of capturing the first value within C:E into column B. Range.SpecialCells can be used to reduce the work to rows where column B is blank.

```
dim blnk as range

with worksheets("sheet1")

    with .range(.cells(2, "B"), .cells(.rows.count,"A").end(xlup).offset(0, 1))

        for each blnk in .specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks)

            blnk.resize(1, 4).merge
            blnk.unmerge

        next blnk

    end with

end with
```